# PictureBox не отображает изображение visual c#

Tags: c#, picturebox

Я новичок в c#, пишу небольшую игру. Её цель ставить звездочки так, чтобы их задело рандомно перемещающееся НЛО. Так вот, когда я пытаюсь поставить звезду иногда Picturebox, её содержащий, не хочет отображаться вообще, а иногда отображается корректно. Для этих звезд заведен отдельный массив из picturebox. Picturebox обновляются в событии paint. Ниже приведен фрагмент кода из события MouseClick. Поясните почему иногда picturebox не хотят отображаться вообще.

```
Bitmap star1 = Properties.Resources.star1;
Bitmap star2 = Properties.Resources.star2;
Bitmap star3 = Properties.Resources.star3;
Bitmap star4 = Properties.Resources.star4;
Bitmap star5 = Properties.Resources.star5;
a.Add(new PictureBox());

a[kol].Location = new Point(e.Location.X - 32, e.Location.Y - 32);
a[kol].Height = 64;
a[kol].Width = 64;
if (type == 1)
{
    a[kol].Image = star1;

}
if (type == 2)
{
    a[kol].Image = star2;

}
if (type == 3)
{
    a[kol].Image = star3;

}
if (type == 4)
{
    a[kol].Image = star4;

}
if (type == 5)
{
    a[kol].Image = star5;

}

Controls.Add(a[kol]);
kol++;
```

Comment: может у вас с вычислением координат проблема, выходит за пределы видимости?

Comment: В том-то и дело что всё с этим в порядке, просто иногда он отображается, а иногда нет. Я отлаживал эту программу и каждый раз проверял всё, в том числе и координаты. Выходит, что Picturebox там есть, просто его не видно. А некоторые видно. При этом с файлом картинки всё в порядке.

Comment: может одна звезда перекрывает другую? Нужно отлаживать уменьшив количество звезд до легко отслеживаемого кол-ва, скажем 5-10 шт. Выводить результаты вычисления координат через `Debug.WriteLine()`.